# Code Help - PHP, Query String, Redirect

Tags: php, query-string

I'm trying to pass variables to a simple PHP script and have it redirect to different URLs depending on the values in the query string.

Here's what I have in bonus.php:

```
<?php

if ($_GET['pid'] == '3') {
    $bonus = "copy-paste-traffic";
}
elseif ($_GET['pid'] == '5') {
    $bonus = "lazy-affiliate-riches";
}

$redirect = "http://affiliatesilverbullet.com/.'$bonus'.-bonus/?mid=.'$_GET['mid']'.&pid=.'$_GET['pid']'.";

echo $redirect;

page_redirect($redirect);

?>
```

I want queries to redirect as follows:

asbfree.com/bonus.php?mid=dstruckman&pid=3 -> affiliatesilverbullet.com/copy-paste-traffic-bonus/?mid=dstruckman&pid=3

asbfree.com/bonus.php?mid=dstruckman&pid=5 -> affiliatesilverbullet.com/lazy-affiliate-riches-bonus/?mid=dstruckman&pid=3

But it's not working.

What am I doing wrong?

Please show me how to fix my bonus.php script to make this work.

Thanks in advance!

Dustin

Comment: "not working" is not an explanation.

Comment: Post the code for "page_redirect()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `header("Location: $redirect");` instead of `page_redirect($redirect);`.

Comment: I think you mean `header("Location: $redirect");`

Comment: Whoops! Thanks Jason for calling out the typo!

Answer (score 1):

I think you may change

`$redirect = "http://affiliatesilverbullet.com/.'$bonus'.-bonus/?mid=.'$_GET['mid']'.&pid=.'$_GET['pid']'.";`

to

`$redirect = "http://affiliatesilverbullet.com/".$bonus."-bonus/?mid=".$_GET['mid']."&pid=".$_GET['pid'];`

EDIT : ...change `elseif` to `else if`, `page_redirect` to `http_redirect`, and remove `echo` or place after redirect function.

Comment: this also did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

One of the issues may be your [variable interpolation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing).
Replace

```
$redirect = "http://affiliatesilverbullet.com/.'$bonus'.-bonus/?mid=.'$_GET['mid']'.&pid=.'$_GET['pid']'.";
```

with

```
$redirect = "http://affiliatesilverbullet.com/{$bonus}-bonus/?mid={$_GET['mid']}&pid={$_GET['pid']}";
```

Next time you post a question it would be helpful to post the error message you are receiving.

Comment: I updated and it's still not working for me. 

The error I get is:

Server error
The website encountered an error while retrieving http://asbfree.com/bonus.php?mid=dstruckman&pid=3. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.

Which you can see if you go to the URL.

Comment: Right, its throwing a 500 error and logging the error message somewhere. I'd check the apache error log.